# Refresh content jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a little project, and I'm making a content show with radio buttons, something like a slideshow gallery, but what i'm trying to do is a big container with  many divs inside with a opacity:1; all  this overlapping 3 containers more with the same characteristics, so when somebody give a clic in a radio button, the  container with opacity:1; will get a opacity:0; and the overlapped container  by the container with opacity:1;  will be visible.

the main problem that I get is when I clic in a radio button to change the content, this (content) doesn't appears until I reload the page, can somebody tell me why this happen? and how to solve it?

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("#op1").prop('checked',true);
$("#op2").prop('checked',true);
$("#op3").prop('checked',true);
$("#op4").prop('checked',true);
//$("#x").prop('checked',false);

if ($("#op1").is(':checked')) {
    if ($('#cont1').hasClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity'))
    {
       $('#cont1').removeClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity').addClass('contenedor-fotos1'); 
    }
     $('.contenedor-fotos2').removeClass('contenedor-fotos2').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
     $('.contenedor-fotos3').removeClass('contenedor-fotos3').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
     $('.contenedor-fotos4').removeClass('contenedor-fotos4').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
    
 }

if ($("#op2").is(':checked')) {
     if ($('#cont2').hasClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity'))
    {
       $('#cont2').removeClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity').addClass('contenedor-fotos2'); 
    }
     $('.contenedor-fotos1').removeClass('contenedor-fotos1').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
     $('.contenedor-fotos3').removeClass('contenedor-fotos3').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
     $('.contenedor-fotos4').removeClass('contenedor-fotos4').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
    
 }
    
if ($("#op3").is(':checked')) {
     if ($('#cont3').hasClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity'))
    {
       $('#cont3').removeClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity').addClass('contenedor-fotos3'); 
    }
     $('.contenedor-fotos1').removeClass('contenedor-fotos1').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
     $('.contenedor-fotos2').removeClass('contenedor-fotos2').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
     $('.contenedor-fotos4').removeClass('contenedor-fotos4').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
    
 }

if ($("#op4").is(':checked')) {
     if ($('#cont4').hasClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity'))
    {
       $('#cont4').removeClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity').addClass('contenedor-fotos4'); 
    }
     $('.contenedor-fotos1').removeClass('contenedor-fotos1').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
     $('.contenedor-fotos2').removeClass('contenedor-fotos2').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
     $('.contenedor-fotos3').removeClass('contenedor-fotos3').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
    
 }
    
});
```

```css
#contenedor-portafolio {
    
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: #222;
}

.fotos-portolio {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #444;
}




.contenedor-fotos1 {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background: red;
    z-index: 10;
}

.contenedor-fotos-opacity {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5%;
    opacity:0;
    z-index: 10;
}



.contenedor-fotos2 {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background: green;
    z-index: 11;
}



.contenedor-fotos3 {
     width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 12;
}



.contenedor-fotos4 {
     width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 13;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>prueba cont-slider</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/content-slider.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/content-slider.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="width:100%; position:absolute; top: 0px; left: -8px;">
        
        <div id="contenedor-portafolio">
            <form>
                <input type="radio" name="opacitylayer" id="op1"/>
                <label for="op1">DISEÑO WEB</label>
                
                <input type="radio" name="opacitylayer" id="op2"/>
                <label for="op2">DISEÑO GRÁFICO</label>
                
                <input type="radio" name="opacitylayer" id="op3"/>
                <label for="op3">DISEÑO 3D</label>
                
                <input type="radio" name="opacitylayer" id="op4"/>
                <label for="op4">FOTOGRAFÍA</label>
            </form>
            <div id="cont1" class="contenedor-fotos1">
                <center>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                </center>
            </div>
            <div id="cont2" class="contenedor-fotos2">
                <center>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                </center>
            </div>
            <div id="cont3" class="contenedor-fotos3">
                <center>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                </center>
            </div>
            <div id="cont4" class="contenedor-fotos4">
                <center>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                </center>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a change handler since you want to run the script whenever user changes the checked status of the radio elements

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $("#op2").prop('checked',true);

  $("#op1, #op2, #op3, #op4").on('change', function(){
    if ($("#op1").is(':checked')) {
      if ($('#cont1').hasClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity'))
      {
        $('#cont1').removeClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity').addClass('contenedor-fotos1'); 
      }
      $('.contenedor-fotos2').removeClass('contenedor-fotos2').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
      $('.contenedor-fotos3').removeClass('contenedor-fotos3').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
      $('.contenedor-fotos4').removeClass('contenedor-fotos4').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');

    }

    if ($("#op2").is(':checked')) {
      if ($('#cont2').hasClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity'))
      {
        $('#cont2').removeClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity').addClass('contenedor-fotos2'); 
      }
      $('.contenedor-fotos1').removeClass('contenedor-fotos1').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
      $('.contenedor-fotos3').removeClass('contenedor-fotos3').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
      $('.contenedor-fotos4').removeClass('contenedor-fotos4').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');

    }

    if ($("#op3").is(':checked')) {
      if ($('#cont3').hasClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity'))
      {
        $('#cont3').removeClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity').addClass('contenedor-fotos3'); 
      }
      $('.contenedor-fotos1').removeClass('contenedor-fotos1').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
      $('.contenedor-fotos2').removeClass('contenedor-fotos2').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
      $('.contenedor-fotos4').removeClass('contenedor-fotos4').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');

    }

    if ($("#op4").is(':checked')) {
      if ($('#cont4').hasClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity'))
      {
        $('#cont4').removeClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity').addClass('contenedor-fotos4'); 
      }
      $('.contenedor-fotos1').removeClass('contenedor-fotos1').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
      $('.contenedor-fotos2').removeClass('contenedor-fotos2').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');
      $('.contenedor-fotos3').removeClass('contenedor-fotos3').addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity');

    }
  }).change() 
});
```

```css
#contenedor-portafolio {
    
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: #222;
}

.fotos-portolio {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #444;
}




.contenedor-fotos1 {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background: red;
    z-index: 10;
}

.contenedor-fotos-opacity {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5%;
    opacity:0;
    z-index: 10;
}



.contenedor-fotos2 {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background: green;
    z-index: 11;
}



.contenedor-fotos3 {
     width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 12;
}



.contenedor-fotos4 {
     width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 13;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>prueba cont-slider</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/content-slider.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/content-slider.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="width:100%; position:absolute; top: 0px; left: -8px;">
        
        <div id="contenedor-portafolio">
            <form>
                <input type="radio" name="opacitylayer" id="op1"/>
                <label for="op1">DISEÑO WEB</label>
                
                <input type="radio" name="opacitylayer" id="op2"/>
                <label for="op2">DISEÑO GRÁFICO</label>
                
                <input type="radio" name="opacitylayer" id="op3"/>
                <label for="op3">DISEÑO 3D</label>
                
                <input type="radio" name="opacitylayer" id="op4"/>
                <label for="op4">FOTOGRAFÍA</label>
            </form>
            <div id="cont1" class="contenedor-fotos1">
                <center>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                </center>
            </div>
            <div id="cont2" class="contenedor-fotos2">
                <center>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                </center>
            </div>
            <div id="cont3" class="contenedor-fotos3">
                <center>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                </center>
            </div>
            <div id="cont4" class="contenedor-fotos4">
                <center>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                <div class="fotos-portolio"></div>
                </center>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

You can simplify that to

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#op2").prop('checked', true);

    var $els = $('#cont1, #cont2, #cont3, #cont4');
    $("#op1, #op2, #op3, #op4").on('change', function () {
        var id = this.id.substring(2), $el = $('#cont'+id);
        if (this.checked) {
            if ($el.hasClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity')) {
                $el.removeClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity').addClass('contenedor-fotos'+id);
            }
            $els.not($el).each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('contenedor-fotos'+this.id.substring(5))
            }).addClass('contenedor-fotos-opacity')
        }
    }).change()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w0axv927/)

Comment: Holy molly man! you are the best! Thanks, really thanks! but, as I am new (really new) in jQuery, can you explain me the simplified version? I can't understand at all what the code is doing :(